# Автоматическая нумерация блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, блок

Добрый день! Прошу помощи! Вопрос в следующем. Есть автоматическая нумерация блоков. Как сделать так, чтобы нумерация заканчивалась на номере 7, т.е. начиная с восьмого блока вместо продолжении нумерации показывалась определенная картинка? Помогите, пожалуйста, решить этот вопрос.

```html
<div class="someclass"> 
  <div class="class"></div>Это первый блок. 
</div> 

<div class="someclass"> 
  <div class="class"></div>Это второй блок 
</div> 

<div class="someclass"> 
  <div class="class"></div>Это третий блок 
</div> 

<div class="someclass"> 
  <div class="class"></div>Это четвертый блок 
</div>
```

```css
.someclass { 
  background: #cccccc; 
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px; 
  margin: 10px; 
  width: 200px; 
  position: relative; 
} 
.class { 
  position: absolute; 
  width: auto; 
  height: 20px; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  background: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
   for (var i = 0; i < $('.someclass').length; i++){ 
      $($('.someclass')[i]).find('.class').text(i+1); 
      console.log($('.someclass')[i]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.someclass').length; i++){
        var block = $($('.someclass')[i]).find('.class');

        if (i < 7) {
            block.text(i+1); 
        } else {
            // URL для картинки может быть любым =)
            block.html('<img src="picture.jpg" />');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, всё работает! Огромное Вам спасибо!